# Python efficient exception handling

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out if there's a more pythonic way to do a specific error handling task. I want to catch multiple specific custom exceptions and do something specific depending on which exception is caught (like use a specific custom exit code, or add a specific log message, etc...). However, I also want, if any exception is raised, to do send an email saying the script didn't complete successfully, had exit code __, the log is at C:\foo\bar.txt

I know I could include everything I want to do in each except, such as:

```
try:
    do_something()
except CustomError1:
    exitcode = 1
    send_error_email(exitcode)
    sys.exit(exitcode)
except CustomError2:
    exitcode = 2
    send_error_email(exitcode)
    sys.exit(exitcode)
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more pythonic or more efficient way of doing it.  I'm imagining something like

```
try:
    do_something()
except CustomError1:
    exitcode = 1
except CustomError2:
    exitcode = 2
except ParrentCustomErrorClass:
    send_error_email()
    sys.exit(exitcode)
```

If it matters, I'm currently stuck with python 2.7, but need to be able to port solution to 3.x when 3rd party applications allow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two idioms I have seen are:

> With `finally`

```
exit_code = None
try:
   do_something()
except CustomError1:
    exit_code = 1
except CustomError2:
    exit_code = 2
finally:
    if exit_code is not None:
        send_error_mail(exit_code)
```

> With ["dictionary dispatch"](https://alysivji.github.io/quick-hit-dictionary-dispatch.html)

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception as e:
    code = {
        CustomError1: 1
        CustomError2: 2
    }.get(type(e))
    if code is None:
        raise
    send_error_email(code)
```

(or if you wanna go full [`PEP572`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)),

```
    ...
    if (code := {
        CustomError1: 1
        CustomError2: 2
    }.get(type(e))) is not None:
         send_error_email(code)
    raise
```

---

If you *control* your exceptions however (and they are not library exceptions) - I do like @scnerd's solution too. If you don't - and want to catch `ValueError`s or `TypeError`s or whatever then one of these is the way to go.

Comment: I had a very similar idea about using a `dict` to store the `Exceptions` and was about to post it when I saw your answer. I didn't know about these recommended ways. Can you explain why it is better to define that `dict` again any time an exception is handled? I would have declared a public dictionary `errors` once containing all the exceptions as keys like you, and whenever an exception had to be handled, did something like `except tuple(errors.keys()) as err: ...code = errors.get(type(err))`. It would be less code but probably not as fast?

Comment: It will be just as fast - marginally different if anything. It just depends if this is a one-off kind of thing or you want to be doing this commonly - in which case your way is better :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you just define the exit codes in the exception types themselves?

```
class ParentCustomErrorClass(Exception):
    exitcode = 999

    def send_error_email(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def die_horribly(self):
        import sys
        self.send_error_email()
        sys.exit(self.exitcode)

class CustomError1(ParentCustomErrorClass):
    exitcode = 1

class CustomError2(ParentCustomErrorClass):
    exitcode = 2

try:
    do_something()
except ParentCustomErrorClass as ex:
    ex.die_horribly()
```

Comment: I'd never really though of adding error handling into an error class before (sounds stupid, but didn't really think of them as a normal class), so thank you for the insight and will possibly use this in future.  For the current project, unfortunately, I don't have control over the error classes however as I'm catching from 3rd party modules.